# compareTo method Franchise class

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist, compareto

```
package prob1;

public class Franchise implements Comparable<Franchise> {
    private String location;
    private double totals = 0;
    private String owner;

    public Franchise(String location,double totals,String owner){
        this.location = location;
        this.totals = totals;
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public String getLocation(){
        return location;
    }
    public double getTotal(){
        return totals;
    }
    public String getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }
    public int compareTo(Franchise that) {
        int stateComparition = this.getLocation().compareTo(that.getLocation()); 
        Double sales = Double.valueOf(this.getTotal());    
        Double thatSales = Double.valueOf(that.getTotal());
        int salesComparition = sales.compareTo(thatSales);    

        if(stateComparition == 0){
            if(salesComparition > 0)
                 return -1;
            else if(salesComparition < 0)
                 return 1;
            else
                 return 0;
        }
           return stateComparition;         
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result = "";
        result = "Owner =  " + getOwner() + " ,State = "+ getLocation() + " ,Sales = " + getTotal() + "\n";

        return result;
    }

}
```

This class has a compareTo method.I was wondering if you guys can explain me in detail what is this method doing...basically I need you guys to trace it and explain me step by step.Thanks a lot!

```
package prob1;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class FracnahiseTester {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ArrayList<Franchise> franchises = new ArrayList<Franchise>();

         Franchise franchaise1 = new Franchise("CA",3300,"Corey");
         Franchise franchaise2 = new Franchise("GA",1000,"Pato");
         Franchise franchaise4 = new Franchise("NC",3300,"Travis");
         Franchise franchaise3 = new Franchise("NC",3500,"Roy");

         franchises.add(franchaise1);
         franchises.add(franchaise2);
         franchises.add(franchaise4);
         franchises.add(franchaise3);

         Collections.sort(franchises);
         for(Franchise i : franchises){
             System.out.println(i);
         }
    }

}
```

This is my tester

Comment: This doesn't really fit the format of a question. Is there something in particular that doesn't work for which you couldn't find an easy answer in documentation or elsewhere on dee internets? Seems kind of like a homework question that you are having a hard time getting right?

Comment: it's a hw problem but work perfectly right, but i just wanted to make sure how does it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can get this info from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), this answer will help understand the concept of compareTo() method for other users who drop by here.

When you are implementing `Comparable` interface, your `compareTo()` method is used to compare different objects,

```
public int compareTo(Franchise that) {
    int stateComparition = this.getLocation().compareTo(that.getLocation()); 
    Double sales = Double.valueOf(this.getTotal());    
    Double thatSales = Double.valueOf(that.getTotal());
    int salesComparition = sales.compareTo(thatSales);    

    if(stateComparition == 0){
        if(salesComparition > 0)
             return -1;
        else if(salesComparition < 0)
             return 1;
        else
             return 0;
    }
       return stateComparition;         
}
```

- `public int compareTo()` used to compare the object passed as argument with the object that calls this method.
- If `this` object is less than `that` object, a negative integer is returned, in your case its `-1`. That means `this` objects comes first before `that` in sorted manner.
- If `this` is equal to `that` object, then `0` should be equal that means objects are equal.
- If `this` is greater than `that` object than a positive integer is returned, in your case, it is `1`. It means `this` comes AFTER `that` when objects of `Franchise` type are sorted.